# Enable kubectl autocompletion on aws cloudshell

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, kubectl, aws-cloudshell

I followed all the instructions in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/included/optional-kubectl-configs-bash-linux/ to enable kubectl autocompletion.

I've the line `source <(kubectl completion bash)` in ~/.bashrc

When I run the command `. ./.bashrc` the autocompletion works fine.
When the shell restarts autocompletion doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem running `kubectl completion bash > $HOME/.bash_completion`